# Weighting multiple objectives in GEKKO

Tags: optimization, gekko

I want to solve a multiobjective optimization problem in GEKKO.

I tried to manually multiply each term of the overall objective function, for example:

```py
a=1
b=10
m.Maximize(a*(x+y))
m.Minimize(b*(x.dt()+y.dt()))
```

But apparently the optimal result is not sensitive to changes in weights a and b. Is there a way to manually impose that an objective is more important than another in GEKKO?

Also, do I have to scale the objective functions manually or does GEKKO take care of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After following John Hedengren's advice, I realized that the lack of sensitivity to the weighting parameters was not cause by how the problem was formulated, but rather by the values of the parameters themselves.

I was initially using values in the range of [1e-2,1e2], but when I tried 1e7, I got a different solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to explicitly define priorities is to use `m.CV()` variable types with `m.options.CV_TYPE=1` to use the [l1-norm objective](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective). From the [Dynamic Optimization](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MultiObjectiveOptimization) course:

> Many optimization problems have multiple competing objectives. These competing objectives are part of the trade-off that defines an optimal solution. Sometimes these competing objectives have separate priorities where one objective should be satisfied before another objective is even considered. This especially arises in model predictive control or other types of dynamic optimization problems. There are competing objectives with a ranked hierarchy. The highest level objectives are satisfied first followed by lower ranked objectives if there are additional degrees of freedom available. The l1-norm objective is a natural way to explicitly rank objectives and simultaneously optimize multiple priorities with a single optimization problem.

With `x=m.CV()` you can scale the objective for each variable with `x.WSPHI` and `x.WSPLO` for upper and lower deviations from a target value. Use `x.COST` to minimize with a positive value and maximize by assigning a negative value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. From my understanding, this route would imply in rewriting the whole problem, or at least a part of it, replacing variables defined using Var() by variables defined using CV() (brief discussion on the subject for example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982481/using-m-cv-vs-m-var).

I'll wait longer to see if anyone knows how to weight objectives defined with Var() variables directly, but if this is not possible then I'll try to implement your solution.

Comment: What you've written in the original question should work to prioritize objectives. It isn't the value of `a` or `b` that determines which one is most important to the optimizer, but the gradient of that objective wrt the variable (Lagrange multiplier). See the KKT conditions for information on how gradient-based optimizers find a solution: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker  Try increasing `a` (or `b`) until the solution changes.